# The sound of cutting board

Tags: verbs, adjectives

I have been searching for a word (verb/adjective) to describe the sound of a knife cutting on a wooden board for a while fruitlessly. What I ended up writing is "intermittent cutting board thumps" which, in my opinion, is pretty rubbish. The word "thud" also doesn't apply as I'm trying to describe a sound that is not dull; the sound a knife makes against a cutting board is pretty sharp and quick.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: *The intermittent sound of a knife chopping on a cutting board*. Here, the sound is inferred from the **action** of the knife.

Comment: You'd probably have to resort to what they do in graphic novels and comic books, and write your own onomatopoeia for this specific of a sound, e.g. *"chop chop chop chop chop"* or *"whick whick whick whick whick"*.

Comment: Please can you provide the full sentence?

Comment: Hiya thanks all. I ended up using what @WeatherVane had suggested. Oh, Andrew, by the way, I do that sometimes but because of the lack of details (which of course is my fault), you couldn't have known what I meant. But thanks for the help either way! :)

Comment: @LironIlayev - I would specifically use the word "sharp" as in your question - "the quick, sharp sound of the knife chop, chop, chopping against the board." Since it is likely a common sound to your readers, describing the sound (as the other comments suggest) should work well.